# Offline App with depended ajax dropdowns - using local sqlitedb

Tags: javascript, ajax, sqlite

I have an offline "app" (web page) using a combination of HTML/CSS/JS/SQLite/JSON working -- leveraging Google Chrome. I am able to successfully store submitted data from a local form to the local SQLite DB - via JS.   I also have a button click function to feed submitted local data up to the Cloud - to a remote internet MySQL database.  Along with that -- I have another simple HTML button which when clicked - can refresh remote data from the Cloud (MySQL database) back to local PC (SQLite) - ultimately refreshing local users SQLite source data - using JSON/PHP APIs (pushing and pulling data)

The one thing that I am currently struggling with, is how to overcome (w/o creating a full blow app or installing WAMP/XAMPP) the development of these local web pages use ajax to drive dependent drop-down menu selections - on the local form (for example: selecting state to then drive another menu for city names) - Within the console error log I see "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: HTTP, data, chrome, chrome-extension, HTTPS" messages.

Is it even possible to do this? - ....Where all of the code is on the local device? (without something like PHP and a web server) - If so, any recommendations?  I can do all of this if it was on our public web server - but for this effort, I need to do all of this locally.

Comment: If you need to keep this application private, you can run it locally on a WAMP/XAMPP server. As long as you don't point real domains to your webserver, only computers on your network will be able to access the application via your server's IP address. Is that good enough for your purposes?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Is it the CORS thing, or you can't be bothered to run a local server for development or what?

Comment: Sounds good, thank you.  It sounds like the WAMP/XAMPP option is what I was really asking about and chasing - I am not opposed to installing and configuring it.  .....I was just wondering if there was something that I was missing simply b/c I never executed an AJAX call exclusively on the "local device" - I thought that I did something wrong -